# Cannot read property "service function" of undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to fetch data from a RESTApi using Angular. The data consists of a list of department objects with pvt attribute departmentName using HTTP get request.

I am trying to use the list to update an angular material dropdown list

I keep getting the error

```
Cannot read property "updateAvailableDepartment" of undefined
```

This is my departmentService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Department} from './department';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DepartmentServiceService {
   private departmentURL: string;

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.departmentURL = 'http://localhost:8080/department/departmentList';
   }

   public updateAvailableDepartment(): Observable<Department[]> {
      return this.http.get<Department[]>(this.departmentURL);
   }

}
```

This is the Department Class

```
export class Department {
  departmentName: string;
}
```

Component class associated with drop down component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DepartmentServiceService} from '../department-service.service';
import {Department} from '../department';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  availableDepartments: Department[];
  private departmentService: DepartmentServiceService;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('hello');
    this.departmentService.updateAvailableDepartment().subscribe(
    data => { this.availableDepartments = data; },
    error => { console.error('There was an error!', error); }
    );
    console.log('hello');
    console.log(this.availableDepartments);
  }
}
```

Code snippet for HTML code

```
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Select a Department *</mat-label>
          <mat-select>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let department of this.availableDepartments" 
              [value]="department.departmentName">
              {{department.departmentName}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should inject the service in `LoginComponent`: `constructor(private departmentService: DepartmentServiceService) { }`.

Comment: Pass DepartmentServiceService into your constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Try without use **this** in HTML, like this

```
     <mat-select>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let department of availableDepartments" 
          [value]="department.departmentName">
          {{department.departmentName}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
```

**this** refers to the component itself for which the template was rendered. On the template you can access only members of the component.

2 - Use service DepartmentServiceService in constructor like this

```
  constructor(private departmentService: DepartmentServiceService) {}
```

Comment: Appreciate the quick response. Just tried that issue still persists.

Comment: I think the error might be raised from the ngOnit() method of the component class. But I am unable to figure out what the error is.

Comment: The second suggestion solved the problem. Thank you